# How to set data to the state after fetching from backend?

Tags: reactjs, axios, mern

I want to get data from the backend and want to set those data to the state in ReactJS. Here is my source code

```
const [eachAsset, setEachAsset] = useState([]);
function ShowModalView(id)
    {
        
            
            axios.get("http://localhost:8070/assets/detail/"+id).then((res)=>{
                
                const data = res.data
                setEachAsset(data)
                //console.log(eachAsset);
            }).catch((err)=>{
                
                console.log(err.message);
            })
        
        
        setShow2(true);
        
        
    }
```

When I uncomment the console log, it shows an empty array. It means, setEachAsset(data) does not work properly. But I want to store data that are getting from the backend to the eachAsset state. What is the problem of this source code?

Answer (score 0):

```
setEachAsset([...data])
```

I hope this would work

Comment: There is an error called " data is not iterable "

Comment: i would advise to use react-query libarary, it would handle all you api response, error very well and u wont need to use setState for that, easy and simple

Comment: `setEachAsset((assets) =>  [...assets , data]);`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using async-await which makes the code easier to read and understand the flow of the program as compared to promise chains.

```js
const [eachAsset, setEachAsset] = useState([]);

const ShowModalView = async (id) => {
    try {
        const resp = await axios.get("http://localhost:8070/assets/detail/"+id);
        setEachAsset(resp.data)
        console.log(resp.data);
    } catch (err) {
        // Handle Error Here
        console.error(err);
    }
    setShow2(true);
}
```

Comment: When I use console.log(eachAsset), it also shows an empty array that means have not set resp.data to the state.

Comment: setEachAsset is an async funtion so if you want to view when it changes you can use useEffect and pass it as a dep and move the console.log inside the use effect